# Bibliography ordered as Author, Article title, Journal, Year, Volume, Issue, and Page, and DOI

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, apa-style

I'm having trouble trying to adapt the structure of my bibliography. Ideally I would want to have them ordered as: Author, article title, journal, year, volume, issue, and page, and DOI.

What I have so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\setcitestyle{aysep={}} 
\bibliographystyle{apalike}

\begin{document}
\citep{<Bibtexkey>}
\bibliography{<myRef>}
\end{document}
```

How do I adapt the set of instructions above to get the output below?

> Cras JJ, Rowe-Taitt CA, Nivens DA, Ligler FS. Comparison of chemical cleaning methods of glass in preparation for silanization. Biosensors and Bioelectronics. 1999;14(9):683-88. https://doi.org/10.1016/S0956-5663(99)00043-3

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Which formatting requirements do you have for entry types other than `@article`?

Comment: You asked, "How do I adapt the set of instructions above to get the output below?" The short answer is, "One cannot adapt the code you've shown to get the desired output." Achieving the desired output requires either editing/modifying a given bibliography style (`apalike`, say) or creating a new bibliography style from scratch. Incidentally, obtaining the desired output by modifying `apalike.bst` would require *multiple changes*, well beyond just moving the spot where the contents of the `year` field would be inserted. Are you sure you want to start off from `apalike`?

Comment: @Mico I really don't mind if you have something different -- as long as it does the job. Thank you very much.

Comment: Please see the answer I just posted.

Answer (score 0):

(too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer)

I can observe at least eight [8!!] differences between the output produced by `apalike` and your desired output. And this list includes only entries of type `@article`; other entry types will likely produce further discrepancies between `apalike`'s output and your desired output.

[image]

[image]

- `apalike` renders names as `Cras, J. J.`, whereas you want `Cras JJ`.
- If there's more than 1 author, `apalike` inserts `and` before the final author; you don't want this particle.
- Placement and form of the year field (this is the only difference you mention in your query): `apalike` produces `(1999).` after the `author` block, whereas you want `1999;` placed after the `journal` field.
- `apalike` italicizes the contents of the `journal` field -- something you do not want.
- `apalike` places a comma after the `journal` field, whereas you want a period (aka full stop)
- If the `pages` field is given by `pages = "683--688"`, `apalike` renders it as `683-688`, whereas you want `683-88`.
- `apalike` ignores the `doi` field; you want it included.
- `apalike` places a period (aka full stop) at the very end of the typeset bibliographic entry -- something you don't want.

Hacking the `apalike.bst` bibliography style file to obtain the desired output would be exceedingly tedious and likely error-prone.

What's the alternative to hacking `apalike`? I suggest you familiarize yourself with `makebst` utility, which is part of the [custom-bib](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/custom-bib/) package. Open a command window and type `pdflatex makebst` to start the menu-driven utility. You'll walk through a series of multiple-choice questions, each one containing a default choice and several alternative choices. At the end, you'll have a bespoke bst file that contains almost all of your formatting choices; the only formatting choice the utility will *not* produce is to abbreviate the `pages` range, i.e., write `683-88` instead of `683-688`.

(That's how I came up with the second screenshot shown above. Post your email address in a comment, and I'll be happy to send you the file `cras.bst`.)

```
\documentclass{article}
%% I obtained the following bib information from Elsevier's website
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@article{crnl:1999,
author  = "J. J. Cras and C. A. Rowe-Taitt and D. A. Nivens and F. S. Ligler",
title   = "Comparison of chemical cleaning methods of glass in preparation for silanization",
journal = "Biosensors and Bioelectronics",
year    = "1999",
volume  = "14",
number  = "8--9",
pages   = "683--688",
doi     = "https://doi.org/10.1016/S0956-5663(99)00043-3",
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\setcitestyle{aysep={}} 
\setlength{\bibhang}{0pt}
\bibliographystyle{cras} % 'cras.bst' produced by the makebst utility
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\citep{crnl:1999}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @Mico. Although I'll still need to have the page range as presented in my post, I'd like to try this out first. Please kindly send the file to smalingangel@yahoo.com. Best regards.